# C libcurl - measure download speed and time remaining

Tags: c, time, download, performance, libcurl

I am using the following code to download files from the internet:

```
size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
{
    size_t written;
    written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 FILE *downloaded_file;
 if ( (downloaded_file = fopen (download_path , "w" ) ) != NULL )
 {
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl)
  {
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "www.asd.com/files/file_to_download.rar");
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, downloaded_file);
   res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
   curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

   if (res == CURLE_OK)
   {
    printf("Download complete!\n");
   }
  }
  fclose(downloaded_file);
 }
}
```

How can I measure the current download speed (e.g. every second) and the remaining time to complete the download?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTPROGRESSFUNCTION).  curl will pass 5 arguments to your callback function, `clientp`, `dltotal`, `dlnow`, `ultotal`, and `ulnow`.  `clientp` is a pointer you provide with `CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA`.  The total parameters are the total amounts that need to be downloaded; the now ones are the amounts so far.  Unknown values are 0.

To use this, you must set `CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS` to 0.

Comment: This is for the progressbar, how can I use this to measure the speed?

Comment: Overall average download speed is dlnow/(current time - start time).  "Current" download speed is a little trickier. First, you need to define what it means.  One possibility is to have an old_time, and old_now.  Then it is (dlnow - oldNow) / (current time - oldTime).

Comment: after 6 years still a very useful comment :P
Thanks that speed = ((NowDownloaded - lastDownloadedBytes) / (QTime().currentTime().second() - oldTime.second()) / 1024); totally worked for me xD

Comment: @КодСерфинг145 I'm trying your code and it prints `nan` and `inf` constantly, but no speed is actually shown.

Answer (score 0):

`CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION` has been deprecated since v7.32.0, instead you can use [`CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION.html), the usage and callback structure (all the arguments `dltotal`, `dlnow` ...etc) are almost the same as `CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION`